# how to fetch the all item name by selecting in dropdown list and display in table

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

```
function fetchdetails() {
  var item = $('#Item').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>TipUp_Loan/item_fetch",
    data: {
      item: item
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      var json = data,
          obj = 
          JSON.parse(json);
      //var prodName =  
      $(e).closest('tr').find('#Product_Name');
      //$(prodName).val(obj.itemname);
      $(this).('#Product_Name').val(obj.itemname);
    }
  });
}
```

this is a script code...

```
public function fetch_item($item)
{
  $this->db->where("pgroup",$item);
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('itemmaster');
  $this->db->join('pgroup','pgroup.pgroupid = itemmaster.catcode','left outer');
  $query = $this->db->get()->row();
  return $query;
}
```

this is model code...
    my prblm is how to fetch the data by select 
    in dropdown list and display in table.now i 
    am having 4 itemname in table it fetch only 
  1 name and it is not display all itemnames...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have issue with your query this is query solution :

```
public function fetch_item($item)
{
  $this->db->where("pgroup",$item);
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('itemmaster');
  $this->db->join('pgroup','pgroup.pgroupid = itemmaster.catcode','left outer');
  $query_result = $this->db->get()->result();

  //pass query result as html

  $output = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Product Name</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>';

  if($query_result !='false'){

      foreach ($query_result as $key => $value) {

          $output .='<tr>
              <td>'.$value->product_name.'</td>
          </tr>';
      }
  }

  $output .="</tbody>
      </table>";

  echo $output;

}
```

after return above query result to script.then you have to set a forloop before pass data to product select tag

below is changed ajax call :

```
function fetchdetails()
{
  var item = $('#Item').val();

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>TipUp_Loan/item_fetch",
        data: {item:item},
        cache: true,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          $('#Product_Name_div').html(data);              
        }
    });
}
```

This is for View file product list display code

```
<div id="Product_Name_div">
</div>
```

Comment: it's simple. like how you set loop to display query result data in select tag.this is also same you have to set script loop to display all data as option . please check edited answer

Comment: i dont want to display in select tag simply it display in table format

Comment: Ok. i have just edited my answer please check for table view

Comment: sir this is code is working but i have  already created the table in view,you have created in model page, i want to display the data in table format  that has been already created table..

Comment: <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb3" name="tb3">
       <thead>
        <tr>
 <th>Product Name</th>
                </tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr >
<td ><input style="width:150px" type="text" id="Product_Name" class="form-control input-xs" name = "Prdtname[]"   > </td>
this is my table i have created